# Why does differential dynamic programming scale $k$ and not the entire term?

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning

In [differential dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_dynamic_programming), why is $k$ scaled by $\alpha$ during line search and not for both $k$ and $K$? In [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search) for comparison it is done for the entire change $p_k$, so that when $\alpha=0$ there is no change.